# How to get overall total in row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a row group in SSRS that calculates totals by each group. However, I would like to get the percentage of each group out of the overall total. However, I do not know how to achieve getting the overall total to work within the same expression.

Right now I have this to get my total of each group:

```
=Sum(Iif(IsNothing(Fields!ID.Value),0,Iif(Fields!STATUS.Value = "Closed",1,0)))
```

But I am not sure how to divide that by the overall total. Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply the same expression, but in a different **Scope**.

e.g. to get the total for the whole Dataset, you will need something like:

```
=Sum(Iif(IsNothing(Fields!ID.Value),0,Iif(Fields!STATUS.Value = "Closed",1,0)), "DataSet1")
```

Where `DataSet1` is the name of the Dataset used by the Table.

Once you have this new expression, simply divide the Row total expression by the Dataset total expression to get the percentage.